# Remove transparency on menu drop down Javascript

Tags: javascript, web

I've been trying to implement a feature that removes the transparency of the dropdown menu on my website so that it is actually readable for visitors.

The code I am currently using, which removes transparency on scroll but not on drop down is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stoptransparency = 100; // when to stop the transparent menu
    var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
    $(window).on('scroll load resize', function() {
        var position = $(this).scrollTop();
        if(position > stoptransparency) {
            $('#transmenu').removeClass('transparency');
        } else {
            $('#transmenu').addClass('transparency');
        }

        lastScrollTop = position;  
    });

    $('#transmenu .dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
    });

    $('#transmenu .dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

I tried changing it to this (and variations of this) but can't seem to get it to work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var stoptransparency = 100; // when to stop the transparent menu
            var lastScrollTop = 0, delta = 5;
            $(this).scrollTop(0);
            $(window).on('scroll load resize', function() {
                var position = $(this).scrollTop();
                if(position > stoptransparency) {
                    $('#transmenu').removeClass('transparency');
                } else {
                    $('#transmenu').addClass('transparency');
                }

                lastScrollTop = position;  
            });

            $('#transmenu .dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown(300);
$('#transmenu').removeClass('transparency');
            });

            $('#transmenu .dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp(300);
$('#transmenu').addClass('transparency');
            });
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the html that this is hooking into it's a bit difficult to answer your question.

But given the fact that scrolling gets the job done, the only element I can see that could be preventing the functionality you want is that your selector to add show event handler is either selecting nothing in particular or an element in the DOM that is not the bootstrap dropdown element that triggers 'show.bs.dropdown', which is my reasoning for the first statement.

You can try the following debug code to verify:

```
// Should log to console with 'selected' if selector works alternatively 'not selected'
console.log($('#transmenu .dropdown').length > 0 ? 'selected' : 'not selected');

// Log to console when show event triggered
$('#transmenu .dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() { 
     console.log('triggered'); 
});
```

Hope that helps you find a solution. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

see the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/on/ and it should become obvious why your fancy named events are never being triggered (without defining any event namespace in the first place).

```
$('#transmenu .dropdown')
.on('show', function() {})
.on('hide', function() {});
```

the DOM selector also might be `#transmenu.dropdown` instead of `#transmenu .dropdown` (depending if `id` and `class` attributes are present on the DOM node to select - or if one selects the parent node by `id` and there is/are nested node/s with a `class` attribute present).